# Handling Option Inside For Comprehension of Futures

Tags: scala, playframework, future, option-type, playframework-2.3

Consider the following code inside a Play Framework controller:

```
val firstFuture = function1(id)
val secondFuture = function2(id)
val resultFuture = for {
  first <- firstFuture
  second <- secondFuture(_.get)
  result <- function3(first, second)
} yield Ok(s"Processed $id")
resultFuture.map(result => result).recover { case t => InternalServerError(s"Error organizing files: $t.getMessage")}
```

Here are some details about the functions:

- `function1` returns `Future[List]`
- `function2` returns `Future[Option[Person]]`
- `function1` and `function2` can run in parallel, but `function3` needs the results for both.

Given this information, I have some questions:

- Although the application is such that this code is very unlikely to be called with an improper id, I would like to handle this possibility. Basically, I would like to return `NotFound` if `function2` returns `None`, but I can't figure out how to do that.
- Will the `recover` call handle an `Exception` thrown any step of the way?
- Is there a more elegant or idiomatic way to write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with Scalaz OptionT. Maybe when you have only one function Future[Optipn[T]] it's overkill, but when you'll start adding more functions it will become super useful

```
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import scalaz.OptionT
  import scalaz.OptionT._
  import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._

  // Wrap 'some' result into OptionT
  private def someOptionT[T](t: Future[T]): OptionT[Future, T] = 
    optionT[Future](t.map(Some.apply))

  val firstFuture = function1(id)
  val secondFuture = function2(id)

  val action = for {
    list <- someOptionT(firstFuture)
    person <- optionT(secondFuture)
    result = function3(list, person)
  } yield result

  action.run.map {
    case None => NotFound
    case Some(result) => Ok(s"Processed $id")
  } recover {
    case NonFatal(err) => InternalServerError(s"Error organizing files: ${err.getMessage}")
  }
```

Comment: I'm a little wary of adding another dependency for this case, but you might be right that Scalaz will pay off with more similar situations.

Comment: it has a lot of useful abstractions that can save you a lot of time, and make code much smaller, I suggest you to start with http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/

Comment: So your solution worked for me after some tweaks. But I have no idea why haha. If you have time, can you provide details on what the `optionT` method does? And what makes the `someOptionT` method necessary?

Comment: I suggest you to start with http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html. To use optionT Future should be Option[T], but firstFuture is just Future[T], basically you can replace it with optionT(firstFuture.map(result => Option(result)))

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using `collect`, and then you can `recover` the `NoSuchElementException`--which yes, will recover a failure from any step of the way. `resultFuture` will either be successful with the mapped `Result`, or failed with the first exception that was thrown.

```
val firstFuture = function1(id)
val secondFuture = function2(id)
val resultFuture = for {
   first <- firstFuture
   second <- secondFuture.collect(case Some(x) => x)
   result <- function3(first, second)
} yield Ok(s"Processed $id")

resultFuture.map(result => result)
   .recover { case java.util.NoSuchElementException => NotFound } 
   .recover { case t => InternalServerError(s"Error organizing files: $t.getMessage")}
```

Comment: Now that I think of it, using `collect` isn't any different than `.map(_.get)`, in this case, since both result in the same exception to be recovered.

Comment: Thought about that approach too, but it feels a bit gross (non-idiomatic) to generate an exception for the `None` case only to catch it later. It might be the easiest way to go though.